# a very simple question about opengl, c++ and objects

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a very simple openGL program in C++. I have made a Sphere object which simply draws a sphere. I want to have a global variable which gets instantiated in main(), i.e. sphere = Sphere(radius,etc), then gets drawn in draw(), i.e. sphere.draw(), but C++ won't let me. Alternatively, if I have the reference to the sphere in main(), then I can't pass it to the draw function because I haven't defined the draw function myself. This pseudocode might explain it a bit better:

```
include "sphere.h"
Sphere sphere;   <- can't do this for some reason

draw()
{
    ...
    sphere.draw()
}

main()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(draw)
    sphere = Sphere(radius, etc)
}
```

I'm sure this is very simple, but its a difficult thing to Google for to find the answer, and believe me I have tried. I understand that using globals are 'bad' but there doesn't seem to be an alternative. I eventually want to have another class called 'world' which contains the references to spheres and a draw function, but yet another problem is that I don't know how to redirect the glutDisplayFunc to a class function. I tried glutDisplayFunc(sphere.draw), obviously this is hideously wrong.

The complier error is:
    ../src/Cplanets.cpp:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘Sphere::Sphere()’
    ../src/Sphere.cpp:28: note: candidates are: Sphere::Sphere(std::string, float, float, float)
    ../src/Sphere.cpp:13: note:                 Sphere::Sphere(const Sphere&)

The sphere class is:

```
/*
 * Sphere.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 3 Mar 2011
 *      Author: will
 */

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Sphere {

public:

    string name;
    float radius;
    float orbit_distance;
    float orbit_time;

    static const int SLICES = 30;
    static const int STACKS = 30;

    GLUquadricObj *sphere;


    Sphere(string n, float r, float od, float ot)

    {

        name = n;
        radius = r;
        orbit_distance = od;
        orbit_time = ot;
        sphere = gluNewQuadric();

}

void draw()
{
    //gluSphere(self.sphere, self.radius, Sphere.SLICES, Sphere.STACKS)
    gluSphere(sphere, radius, SLICES, STACKS);
}

};
```

Comment: What do you mean "C++ won't let me"? What's the specific error message?

Comment: If you post the compiler error it will be easier to help you. Posting the definition of sphere will probably help too.

Comment: Does `Sphere` have a constructor that takes no parameters?

Comment: @suszterpatt: its 'no matching function for call to ‘Sphere::Sphere()’'

Comment: The sphere class is: class Sphere {

public:

 string name;
 float radius;
 float orbit_distance;
 float orbit_time;

 static const int SLICES = 30;
 static const int STACKS = 30;

 GLUquadricObj *sphere;


 Sphere(string n, float r, float od, float ot)

 {

  name = n;
  radius = r;
  orbit_distance = od;
  orbit_time = ot;
  sphere = gluNewQuadric();




 }

 void draw()
 {
  //gluSphere(self.sphere, self.radius, Sphere.SLICES, Sphere.STACKS)
  gluSphere(sphere, radius, SLICES, STACKS);
 }

};

Comment: Yeah, so a sphere must have a name, a size, and some other attributes. You have to specify that when you construct the sphere, there are no defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with two constructor calls:

```
Sphere sphere;
```

This tries to call the default constructor `Sphere::Sphere()` which is not declared.

```
sphere = Sphere(radius, etc);
```

This calls the constructor taking two arguments, which I presume is the only one provided.

Do it like this:

```
include "sphere.h"
Sphere *sphere;

draw()
{
    ...
    sphere->draw();
}

main()
{
    sphere = new Sphere(radius, etc);
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
}
```

Comment: Or define a constructor that takes no arguments :) +1

Comment: his class has one ctor: <code>Sphere(string n, float r, float od, float ot)</code> that takes four arguments. He can make the global <code>Sphere sphere(1,2,3,4);</code>

Comment: Or add the required arguments to the global variable. There is not use in first declaring an uninitialized pointer, and then call the constructor later.

Comment: @luke: then you are constructing/destructing/constructing again. What a waste.

Comment: @Bo persson: You can only do that when all the arguments are known before invoking main(). I'd bet that's not the case here.

Comment: @Axel: waste?  Technically speaking I suppose, but this is an early experiment by a beginner.  Constructing the object twice is no greater sin than not initializing the Sphere* to NULL, and then making null checks everywhere it's used.  We're both trying to keep the answer simple.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm coming from a java/python background where classes work a bit differently.

Answer (score 1):

Sphere class has overridden the default constructor. If no constructor is specified in the class definition, the compiler automatically provides the default constructor (i.e., `Sphere::Sphere()`). Since the `Sphere` class has overridden it with a constructor taking four arguments, it's the job of class itself to specify the default one.

Comment: There seems to be a constructor (or two) in the class. Just not a default constructor - what does a default sphere look like?

Comment: Default constructor is the constructor that takes no arguments( i.e., `Sphere::Sphere()`). When the OP said - `Sphere sphere;`- call to the default constructor is invoked. Since there is not one, compiler reports. How ever, if `Sphere` class has no constructor at all, compiler would provide the default one in that case.

Comment: I think he asked what the default sphere looks like, in order to know how to create a (useful) default constructor.

Comment: @Axel - I answered the portion of OP comment - `Sphere sphere;   <- can't do this for some reason`